# Plotting a grouped 2 dimensional vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to make a plot of a 2-dimensional vector (2D Plot). But I don't want all the datapoints to have the same color on the plot. Each datapoint corresponds to a group.  I want to  have different colors for each group of datapoints.

```
class=[1 3 2 5 2 5 1 3 3 4 2 2 2]
```

says each datapoint belongs to which group

```
X=[x1,y1;x2,y2;x3,y3;.....]
```

the number of these datapoints are the same as the number of elements in the class vector.

Now I want to plot these based on colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SCATTER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/scatter.html) to easily plot data with different colors. I agree with @gnovice on using `classID` instead of `class`, by the way.

```
scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),6,classID); %# the 6 sets the size of the marker.
```

**EDIT**

If you want to display a legend, you have to either use [@yuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812633/plotting-a-grouped-2-dimensional-vector-in-matlab/2812986#2812986)'s, or [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812633/plotting-a-grouped-2-dimensional-vector-in-matlab/2812694#2812694) solution.

*GSCATTER*

```
%# plot data and capture handles to the points
hh=gscatter(randn(100,1),randn(100,1),randi(3,100,1),[],[],[],'on');
%# hh has an entry for each of the colored groups. Set the DisplayName property of each of them
set(hh(1),'DisplayName','some group')
```

*PLOT*

```
%# create some data
X = randn(100,2);
classID = randi(2,100,1);
classNames = {'some group','some other group'}; %# one name per class
colors = hsv(2); %# use the hsv color map, have a color per class

%# open a figure and plot
figure
hold on
for i=1:2 %# there are two classes
id = classID == i;
plot(X(id,1),X(id,2),'.','Color',colors(i,:),'DisplayName',classNames{i})
end
legend('show')
```

You may also want to have a look at [grouped data](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/bqziops.html) if you have the statistics toolbox.

Comment: What is interesting, you can use vector same length as classID as 3rd argument to differentiate classes by symbol size. Try `scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),classID*1000,'r.')` to plot the bubbleplot.

Comment: Thank you, I found this also but yours is better:
gscatter(m(:,2),m(:,1),classID,'brgyckm','o')

Comment: Is there any ways to get the legend for this?

Comment: @Hossein: Not for scatter, but for the other two.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, since [CLASS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/class.html) is a built-in function, I would name your vector `classID` instead.

Then, for each value in `classID` you can do the following:

```
index = (classID == 1);            %# Logical index of where classID is 1
plot(X(index,1),X(index,2),'r.');  %# Plot all classID 1 values as a red dot
hold on;                           %# Add to the existing plot
```

Comment: Thank you, I found this also but yours is better:
gscatter(m(:,2),m(:,1),classID,'brgyckm','o'). and thank you for the comment for "class".

Answer (score 2):

Look also at the [GSCATTER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/gscatter.html) function from Statistics Toolbox. You can specify color, size and symbol for each group just once.

```
gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),classID,'bgrcm');
```

or just

```
gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),classID); %# groups by color by default
```